# tempfile object skips lines in for loop

Tags: python-2.7, temporary-files

I read data from a csv file, perform some normalization on each row and then write it into a temp file. The temp file object is created in the main() function as code in one file writes to it and code in another file reads from it. This is to avoid importing large files into memory.

However, the following script writes only a subset of rows into the file. When I replace `temp_file.write(row)` with a `print` statement all rows are printed to stdout.

Can someone help me understand why `print` returns all rows but only a subset is written to the temp file.

Update: I added the `normalize()` method to the `main()` method and the results are correct. I suspect the issue is something to do with passing the tempfile object name to another python file and writing to it from that file.

Main Method

```
def main():

    [argparse code here - removed for brevity]

    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()

    if os.path.isfile(args.input_file):
        normalize.normalize_file(args.input_file, temp_file)
    else:
        print 'Please supply a valid source file'   

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Method imported from another file

```
def normalize_file(csv_file, temp_file):

    with open(csv_file) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for line in file:
            row = line.lower()
            matchStr = re.search(r'\\users\\\w+\\',row, re.I)
            if matchStr:
                row = row.replace(matchStr.group(), '\\users\\usr\\')
            matchStr = re.search(r'\w:\\',row, re.I)
            if matchStr:
                row = row.replace(matchStr.group(), '\\')
            temp_file.write(row)
            #if I put print here all rows are printed out correctly
```

Comment: how do you open and close `temp_file`?

Comment: I use `temp_file = TemporaryFile()` in the `main()` function, and then pass the object name as an argument to other functions

Comment: ...and you explicitly close the file handle? Have you read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile)

Comment: I assumed it will be implicitly closed. But I added an explicit statement at the end of  `main()` function and still getting the same results